# Why is my c++ singleton not working on Clion?

Tags: c++, singleton

I want to have a singleton in my project but some errors occur

this is my codes in three separate files.:

```
//---------------My main.cpp code

#include <iostream>
#include "Sports/BBVB.h"


int main() {
    bbvb;
    return 0;
}


// ---------------------------my BBVB.h code
#ifndef SAMAVAR_BBVB_H
#define SAMAVAR_BBVB_H

typedef struct VBResult{
    int set1=-1;
    int set2=-1;
    int set3=-1;
    int set4=-1;
    int set5=-1;
}VBResult;

#include "Sport.h"
#include "../TournamentStuf/Tournament.h"

class BBVB: public Sport {
protected:
    vector<Tournament<VBResult>> tours;
public:
    static BBVB& getInstance(){
        static BBVB b;
        return b;
    }
private:
    BBVB(){}

public:
    BBVB(BBVB const&)=delete;
    void operator=(BBVB const&) = delete;


    //-------------Setter------------

    //------------Getter-------------
    vector<Tournament<VBResult>> getTours() const;
    Tournament<VBResult> getTourById(int id) const;

    //----------Others---------------
    void addTour(Tournament<VBResult> v);

};

BBVB &bbvb=BBVB::getInstance(); 



#endif //SAMAVAR_BBVB_H





//------------------my Store and restore code
#ifndef SAMAVAR_STOREANDRESTORE_H
#define SAMAVAR_STOREANDRESTORE_H


#include "../Sports/BBVB.h"
#include "../Sports/PingPong.h"
#include "../Sports/Wrestling.h"

void Start(BBVB &b);
void Update(const BBVB &b);

void Start(PingPong &p);
void Update(const PingPong &p);

void Start(Wrestling &w);
void Update(const Wrestling &w);





#endif //SAMAVAR_STOREANDRESTORE_H
```

I have a bbvb instance of BBVB but it says you have multiple definitions of it.

I'm new to Clion and I don't have enough information about somethings like cmake and I feel the problem is because of it.
I want to have something like cout and cin in iostream.so by including my BBVB I can access this object.

Clion shows error below:
`` CMakeFiles\Samavar.dir/objects.a(BBVB.cpp.obj):BBVB.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `bbvb'
CMakeFiles\Samavar.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
CMakeFiles\Samavar.dir/objects.a(StoreAndRestore.cpp.obj):StoreAndRestore.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `bbvb'
CMakeFiles\Samavar.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):Samavar-master/Sports/BBVB.h:24: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

Comment: Simply remove `BBVB &bbvb=BBVB::getInstance();` from the header file. It's not needed.

Comment: Storing a reference to your singleton in a global variable is pretty odd. Most people use singletons to pretend that they’re not using global state.

Comment: if you strangely want to memorize the address of the instance in a variable _declare_ it in the header file and _define_ it is a source file, do not _define_ it in the header file. But better to not have the global var _bbvb_ ...

Comment: By making a global reference to your singleton you are reintroducing the static initialization bug that your singleton design is supposed to remove. You should either always call `BBVB::getInstance();` every time or make local references, not global ones.